# howto change voice in festival

Tags: festival

in my /usr/share/festival/voices/english....I have kal_diphone folder which is English male voice but now I want to change English male voice to female voice so ..I downloaded " cmu_us_clb_arctic-0.95-release.tar.gz ...then followed following step ...

```
cd /usr/share/festival/voices/english/
sudo tar jxf cmu_us_clb_arctic-0.95-release.tar.bz2
sudo ln -s cmu_us_clb_arctic cmu_us_clb_arctic_clunits
sudo cp /etc/festival.scm /etc/festival.scm.backup
sudo echo "(set! voice_default 'voice_cmu_us_clb_arctic_clunits)" >>  etc/festival.scm

error is bash : /etc/festival.scm : permission denied...
```

so I used the following command =

```
gksu gedit /etc/festival.scm
```

after that /etc/festival.scm file is opened and then at the end of file I typed

```
(set! voice_default 'voice_cmu_us_clb_arctic_clunits)
```

and then I saved it
after that i typed festival on terminal it has given following error :

```
SIOD ERROR: unbound variable : f2b_f0_lr_start
closing a file left open: /usr/share/festival/init.scm
festival: fatal error exiting.
```

so i again opened /etc/festival.scm and removed that

```
(set! voice_default 'voice_cmu_us_clb_arctic_clunits)
```

and then it started to work...so please tell me how to change voice from male to female...

Comment: please, no abbreviations

Comment: I found a similar error [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/two-issues-with-festival-479512/) - stating that it happened only with that particular voice. Only, in that case, it was `voice_cmu_us_awb_arctic_hts` and not `voice_cmu_us_clb_arctic_clunits`. Could you try a different default voice and see if you get the same error?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error with the same voice_cmu_us_awb_arctic_hts voice (on Raspberry Pi's port of Ubuntu).

I specifically need that Edinburgh-accented voice rather than any of the others in that package (which I haven't even downloaded - space is limited on the RPi)

The error doesn't happen if you substitute 'kal_diphone' for 'us_awb_arctic_hts'.

Does this help?

```
root@hive0001:/home/pi# fgrep f2b_f0_lr_start /usr/share/festival/voices/english/cmu_us_awb_arctic_clunits/*/*.scm
/usr/share/festival/voices/english/cmu_us_awb_arctic_clunits/festvox/cmu_us_awb_arctic_f0model.scm:  (set! f0_lr_start f2b_f0_lr_start)
```

FOUND IT!  There's a commented-out line in /usr/share/festival/voices/english/cmu_us_awb_arctic_clunits/festvox/cmu_us_awb_arctic_f0model.scm:

```
;(require 'f2bf0lr)
```

just add it back in...

Comment: (require 'f2bf0lr) was not commented out for me, but adding the voice change command (set! voice_default 'voice_cmu_us_clb_arctic_clunits) to festival.scm still has no effect.